# Long delay before view reflects updated $scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular 1.4.X app, I have some code like this in the controller

```
function submitForm() {
    $scope.submissionInProgress = true;
    myService.veryExpensiveOperation();
    $scope.submissionInProgress = false;
}
```

In the view, I try to use `$scope.submissionInProgress` to show/hide a spinner while `veryExpensiveOperation()` (a synchronous operation) is in progress.

```
<div ng-show="submissionInProgress" class="spinner">
    Please wait...
</div>
```

However, what actually happens is that the spinner isn't displayed until `veryExpensiveOperation()` has almost completed. In other words, it seems there's a delay of a few seconds between when `$scope.submissionInProgress = true` is called, and when the spinner is actually shown.

Comment: Does the page have a lot of bindings? Try to use a diagnostic tool such as https://github.com/angular/batarang.

Comment: Is ``veryExpensiveOperation`` an async operation?

Comment: @LeonardoChaia no, it's synchronous

Comment: @Dónal, the `submitForm` is called from an AngularJS context? I mean, its' not called from an external library that would need to be wrapped in an `$scope.$apply` ?

Comment: @LeonardoChaia it's called from an AngularJS context

Comment: You can try using `$scope.$apply()` right after the `true` assignment even if you are in the Angular context, to force a digest. My best guess is that there are a lot of bindings in the page, causes a lot of watches, which in turn cause slow change detection and slow DOM update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I fixed this using `$timeout` like so:

```
function submitForm() {
    $scope.submissionInProgress = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        myService.veryExpensiveOperation();
        $scope.submissionInProgress = false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then $http requests are **asynchronous**. The value of `$scope.submissionInProgress` gets changed before the request is completed.

If you make an `$http` request you should better toggle `$scope.submissionInProgress` inside the `resolve` function.

e.g.

```
    function submitForm() {

        $scope.submissionInProgress = true;
        myService.veryExpensiveOperation().then(successCallback, failCallback);

        function successCallback() {
          //..Do whatever you have to do and then set the $scope on false.
          $scope.submissionInProgress = false;
        }

        function failCallback() {
          //Same here
          $scope.submissionInProgress = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: That is not relevant to the question, his problem is that the first assignment `$scope.submissionInProgress = true` takes too much time to actually show the spinner.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use callbacks

#### callback

```
function submitForm() {
    $scope.submissionInProgress = true;
    myService.veryExpensiveOperation(function() {
        $scope.submissionInProgress = false;
    });
}
```

and the function veryExpensiveOperation:

```
veryExpensiveOperation = function(callback) {
...
success: function() {
   if(typeof callback == "Function") {
      callback();
   }
}
...
}
```

Comment: That is not relevant to the question, his problem is that the first assignment `$scope.submissionInProgress = true` takes too much time to actually show the spinner.

Comment: @RonDadon well its clearly the problem `submissionInProgress = false` is called very fast...

Comment: No, it is not. If `submissionInProgress = false` was called too fast, the spinner would **never** show, not showed in delay. Unless the question is wrong...

Comment: @RonDadon sorry I don't get your argue. I telling the same as you. The `submissionInProgress = true` and `submissionInProgress = false` are setted almost immediately, And this problem can be solved with callback.

Comment: You say that `submissionInProgress = true` is being overwritten immediately by `submissionInProgress = false`. If that was the case, the spinner would never show up, or show up for a very short period and then removed, before `veryExpensiveOperation` is completed. According to the question, the problem is `seems there is a delay of a few seconds between when $scope.submissionInProgress = true is called, and when the spinner is actually shown` - that is not the same thing. Again, unless the person who asked the question did not put it right.

Comment: @RonDadon ok... let's see what does he ment.

Comment: @RonDadon your understanding of the problem is correct